# How many ways to select 3 green balls in a row twice

Tags: combinatorics

There are $12$ balls in the basket, $6$ green, and $6$ red. Each ball has a equal probability of getting selected. Now I randomly select the ball one at a time without order and without replacement. How many different ways can I select $3$ green balls in a row twice?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address  the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Do you mean to ask, how many ways are there to withdraw balls such that there are two separate *runs* of green balls, where a run is 3 balls in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the 3 green balls in a row as one object. So you would have 2 of those objects (since you want twice the 3 green balls in a row).  So in total we have 8 objects now, 6 red balls and 2 green objects. So the amount of different ways to select the 2 green objects out of the total 8 objects would be $\binom{8}{2}=28$.